# How to count with a label in Swift2

Tags: swift2, counting

I have 1 Button and 1 Label. When I tap the Button, the label should count to the number end. Now it shows immediately the end result. How can I make it so that every number between is also shown? Is there existing a function for doing that (start and count to a number with special effects)?

Thanks

```
var start = 0
var end = 10
@IBAction func Button1(sender: UIButton) {
    while start <= end {
        Label1.text = "\(start)"
        start = start + 1
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect to do in this button , please explain more . Do you want to display 1 -10  as label title ? or what else ?

Comment: When I press the Button, the Label should show: 0 then after a second 1 then after a second 2 then after a second 3....until 10.

Comment: Like a clock ticking ?

Comment: Yes, like a clock ticking, probably a little bit faster when it counts to 100; I need an NSTimer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one ,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var start = 0
var end = 10

var timer = NSTimer()

func updateTime() {

    if start == end {

    timer.invalidate()

    } else {


        start++

        Label1.text = "\(start)"
    }




}

@IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {


        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

You can change the fast by changing NSTimer interval  currently set to 0.5 , set what ever you want

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot!